# Kali Linux live USB persistence

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

A tutorial explained that persistence on a live USB instance of Kali Linux is achieved by a different partition.

https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence/

How can I modify files stored in the system's partition like:

```
/etc/network/interface
```

or

```
/etc/default/keyboard
```

and make them persistent?
Is it possible to maintain settings that I've modified?

Comment: What tutorial is that, update your post with a link

Answer (score 1):

No, you will keep those changes because that parition will be "merged" with `/` as specified in `persistence.conf`.

```
/ union
```