# Kali Linux 2.0 live USB updates not working

Tags: kali-linux, live-usb, persistence

I can boot from USB drive to [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/), but when I reboot the system, all previous updates and files saved just vanish.

I have done almost everything the [Kali Linux official documents](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence) tell me to do, except that after I `dd` the ISO to my USB drive, I used the `parted` command to create a new partition named 'work' and created the `persistence.conf` file in my Ubuntu system, instead of rebooting into Kali Linux live from the USB drive to create the partition and so on.

While I searched the Internet for things like "Kali Linux live boot from USB", I encountered many [tutorials for installing Kali Linux live usb](http://hackerjuan.com/kali-linux/first-things-first-kali-linux-live-usb-persistence-encrypted-persistence/). These tutorials provide quite similar instructions as the official documents.

I also noticed this question ([Kali Linux live usb persistance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190436/kali-linux-live-usb-persistance)) on Unix&Linux. I don't quite understand this --"that partition will be 'merged' with / as specified in persistence.conf".

Please help me sort things out.

EDIT 1:
I made a [post(at #2)](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26731-How-to-make-a-persistent-usb-Kali2-0-flash-drivemake-a-persistent-usb-Kali2-0-flash-drive) at [Kali Linux Forums](http://forums.kali.org/) yesterday to describe my problem in more detail.

Comment: easy enough, the files in that partition will be the modifications that you have done to your kali live environment.